# Limit selections in a listbox in vb6

Tags: vb6, listbox, multiple-select

How can I limit the selection of **ListBox** in **VB6**?
What I want: ***User can select maximum 8 Item from ListBox.***

I am using this code:

```
Private Sub lstBox1_Click()
     If lstBox1.SelCount > 8 Then
        MsgBox "Maximum 8 items can be selected."             
       'I want here return false
     End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
lstBox1.Selected(lstBox1.ListIndex) = False
```

Example:

```
Private Sub lstBox1_Click()
     If lstBox1.SelCount > 8 Then
        MsgBox "Maximum 8 items can be selected."             
       'I want here return false
        lstBox1.Selected(lstBox1.ListIndex) = False
     End if
End Sub
```